# Where can I download Tensorflow v0.9 from?

Tags: tensorflow

I only have the CudaNN v4. Tensorflow 0.10 needs v5. However the earlier versions worked fine. Is there some place I can download tensorflow version 0.9 from?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some links (mac/linux)

https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/tensorflow-0.9.0-py2-none-any.whl
https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/tensorflow-0.9.0-py3-none-any.whl
https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/gpu/tensorflow-0.9.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl